# Weblogic filestore, Transaction has timed out when making request

Tags: timeout, jms, weblogic

We are using distributed JMS on weblogic and some times ResourceAccessException occurs. We tried deleting filestores, restarting servers and changing JTA timeout to 300 seconds. (default is 30 seconds).

But we are getting the same error. What could be the reason?

Thanks

```
Caused by: javax.transaction.SystemException: start() failed on resource 'WLStore_COLUMBUS-ADA-PROD-DMN_ColumbusADAFileStore': XAER_RMERR : A resource manager error has occured in the transaction branch
    weblogic.transaction.internal.ResourceAccessException: Transaction has timed out when making request to XAResource 'WLStore_COLUMBUS-ADA-PROD-DMN_ColumbusADAFileStore'.
    at weblogic.transaction.internal.XAResourceDescriptor.startResourceUse(XAResourceDescriptor.java:670)
    at weblogic.transaction.internal.XAServerResourceInfo.start(XAServerResourceInfo.java:1230)
    at weblogic.transaction.internal.XAServerResourceInfo.xaStart(XAServerResourceInfo.java:1164)
    at weblogic.transaction.internal.XAServerResourceInfo.enlist(XAServerResourceInfo.java:296)
    at weblogic.transaction.internal.ServerTransactionImpl.enlistResource(ServerTransactionImpl.java:522)
    at weblogic.transaction.internal.ServerTransactionImpl.enlistResource(ServerTransactionImpl.java:449)
    at weblogic.store.gxa.internal.GXAResourceImpl.enlist(GXAResourceImpl.java:442)
    at weblogic.messaging.kernel.internal.KernelImpl.getGXATransaction(KernelImpl.java:570)
    at weblogic.messaging.kernel.internal.QueueImpl.send(QueueImpl.java:329)
    at weblogic.jms.backend.BEDestinationImpl.sendIssueMessage(BEDestinationImpl.java:1873)
    at weblogic.jms.backend.BEDestinationImpl.send(BEDestinationImpl.java:2108)
    at weblogic.jms.backend.BEDestinationImpl.wrappedSend(BEDestinationImpl.java:2051)
    at weblogic.jms.backend.BEDestinationImpl.invoke(BEDestinationImpl.java:1539)
    at weblogic.messaging.dispatcher.Request.wrappedFiniteStateMachine(Request.java:961)
    at weblogic.messaging.dispatcher.DispatcherImpl.dispatchAsyncInternal(DispatcherImpl.java:139)
    at weblogic.messaging.dispatcher.DispatcherImpl.dispatchAsync(DispatcherImpl.java:115)
    at weblogic.messaging.dispatcher.Request.dispatchAsync(Request.java:1303)
    at weblogic.jms.dispatcher.Request.dispatchAsync(Request.java:96)
    at weblogic.jms.frontend.FEProducer.doDispatch(FEProducer.java:888)
    at weblogic.jms.frontend.FEProducer.sendRetryDestination(FEProducer.java:1021)
    at weblogic.jms.frontend.FEProducer.send(FEProducer.java:1405)
    at weblogic.jms.frontend.FEProducer.invoke(FEProducer.java:1466)
    at weblogic.messaging.dispatcher.Request.wrappedFiniteStateMachine(Request.java:961)
    at weblogic.messaging.dispatcher.DispatcherImpl.syncRequest(DispatcherImpl.java:184)
    at weblogic.messaging.dispatcher.DispatcherImpl.dispatchSyncNoTran(DispatcherImpl.java:287)
    at weblogic.jms.dispatcher.DispatcherAdapter.dispatchSyncNoTran(DispatcherAdapter.java:59)
    at weblogic.jms.client.JMSProducer.toFEProducer(JMSProducer.java:1293)
    at weblogic.jms.client.JMSProducer.deliveryInternal(JMSProducer.java:796)
    at weblogic.jms.client.JMSProducer.sendInternal(JMSProducer.java:541)
    at weblogic.jms.client.JMSProducer.sendWithListener(JMSProducer.java:394)
    at weblogic.jms.client.JMSProducer.send(JMSProducer.java:384)
    at weblogic.jms.client.WLProducerImpl.send(WLProducerImpl.java:970)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.doSend(JmsTemplate.java:592)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.doSend(JmsTemplate.java:569)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate$4.doInJms(JmsTemplate.java:546)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:466)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.send(JmsTemplate.java:543)
    at com.turkcellteknoloji.calypso.jms.SendToJms.insertJms(SendToJms.java:35)
    at com.turkcellteknoloji.calypso.action.impl.SentTransactionToJms.execute(SentTransactionToJms.java:15)
    at com.turkcellteknoloji.calypso.service.impl.Service.execute(Service.java:36)
    at com.turkcellteknoloji.calypso.service.impl.JmsService.onMessage(JmsService.java:21)
    at com.turkcellteknoloji.calypso.service.impl.JmsService.onMessage(JmsService.java:12)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:534)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:495)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:467)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:323)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:261)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:977)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:969)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:871)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
    Caused by: weblogic.transaction.internal.TimedOutException: Transaction has timed out when making request to XAResource 'WLStore_COLUMBUS-ADA-PROD-DMN_ColumbusADAFileStore'.
    at weblogic.transaction.internal.XAResourceDescriptor.startResourceUse(XAResourceDescriptor.java:673)
    ... 50 more

    at weblogic.transaction.internal.XAServerResourceInfo.xaStart(XAServerResourceInfo.java:1188)
    at weblogic.transaction.internal.XAServerResourceInfo.enlist(XAServerResourceInfo.java:296)
    at weblogic.transaction.internal.ServerTransactionImpl.enlistResource(ServerTransactionImpl.java:522)
    at weblogic.transaction.internal.ServerTransactionImpl.enlistResource(ServerTransactionImpl.java:449)
    at weblogic.store.gxa.internal.GXAResourceImpl.enlist(GXAResourceImpl.java:442)
    ... 44 more
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to change the"Synchronous Write Policy"? It affects the JMS file store's performance, scalability, and reliability.

Answer (score 0):

Adding similar issue found with Weblogic hosted application kept failing with little or no reason with stack trace:

```
Caused by: weblogic.jms.common.JMSException: weblogic.messaging.kernel.KernelException: Error enlisting GXA transaction
    at weblogic.jms.dispatcher.DispatcherAdapter.convertToJMSExceptionAndThrow(DispatcherAdapter.java:110)
    at weblogic.jms.dispatcher.DispatcherAdapter.dispatchSyncTran(DispatcherAdapter.java:53)
    at weblogic.jms.client.JMSProducer.toFEProducer(JMSProducer.java:1300)
    at weblogic.jms.client.JMSProducer.deliveryInternal(JMSProducer.java:807)
    at weblogic.jms.client.JMSProducer.sendInternal(JMSProducer.java:543)
    at weblogic.jms.client.JMSProducer.sendWithListener(JMSProducer.java:394)
    at weblogic.jms.client.JMSProducer.send(JMSProducer.java:384)
    at weblogic.jms.client.WLProducerImpl.send(WLProducerImpl.java:970)
    at weblogic.deployment.jms.WrappedMessageProducer.send(WrappedMessageProducer.java:188)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.doSend(JmsTemplate.java:626)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.doSend(JmsTemplate.java:597)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate$3.doInJms(JmsTemplate.java:562)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:484)
```

With little information available, followed some other suggestions to re-create the  JMS data store which could have been corrupted.

In our case located here:

..fmw_home/user_projects/domains/ipp_domain/servers/myapplicationName/data/store/default - filename *WLS*******.DAT

A graceful shutdown to allow as many as possible messages to be resolved is suggested, then shut down application and Weblogic Server before removing the file (would suggest a backup).

After a restart, these issues disappeared, and no more errors were logged, but I'm not sure what the cause was. You would probably have to accept that any transactional data in the JMS queue will be lost.